# BigQuery - Extract last entry of each group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one table where multiple records inserted for each group of product. Now, I want to extract (SELECT) only the last entries. For more, see the screenshot. The yellow highlighted records should be return with select query.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> The HAVING MAX and HAVING MIN clause for the ANY_VALUE function is now in preview

`HAVING MAX` and `HAVING MIN` were just introduced for some aggregate functions - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#February_06_2023

with them query can be very simple - consider below approach

```
select any_value(t having max datetime).*
from your_table t
group by t.id, t.product
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below as well

```sql
 SELECT *
   FROM sample_table
QUALIFY DateTime = MAX(DateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Product);
```

If you're more familiar with an aggregate function than a window function, below might be an another option.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM sample_table t
 GROUP BY t.ID, t.Product
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jaytiger. Can you guide me which book I must buy to learn BigQuery?

Comment: You can consider this book https://www.amazon.com/Google-BigQuery-Definitive-Warehousing-Analytics/dp/1492044466   but the best place to learn BigQuery, I believe, is the official document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax and here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to do partition based on key and selecting required based on defining order by field.

**For Example:**

```
select * from (
select *,
rank() over (partition by product, order by DateTime Desc) as rank
 from `project.dataset.table`)
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to select last record of each group:

```
Select Top(1) * from Tablename group by ID order by DateTime Desc
```