# Transposing Country Population Data in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using the dataset `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_global_population.population_by_country`, and I'd like to convert this data into something along the lines of *country, country_code, year, population*.

| country | country_code | year_1960 | ... | year_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| World | WLD | 3032019978 | ... | 7594270356 |
| Canada | CAN | 17909009 | ... | 37058856 |

to...

| country | country_code | year | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| World | WLD | 1960 | 3032019978 |
| World | WLD | 2018 | 7594270356 |
| Cananda | CAN | 1960 | 17909009 |
| Canada | CAN | 2018 | 37058856 |

The trouble for me is there are 264 unique rows, and 60 'year' columns'.

I suspect there's a way to transpose the data without using 60 `case when` statements (I'm not even sure that many are allowed). I *was* able to get the results I was looking for using a couple of UDFs based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75395582/is-there-a-way-to-use-window-funtions-over-a-specific-column-value-instead-of-a) post, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way that doesn't rely on those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unpivot in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832170/how-to-unpivot-in-bigquery)

Comment: Previous my answer in the link tried not to use a dynamic sql. If you want a *elegant* way, you can consider *unpivot* query along with a *dynamic sql*

Comment: @nbk the problem with a lot of the UNPIVOT documentation is that they use the same technique that I mentioned I wanted to avoid in the original question; listing out every field you want to pivot on.

Comment: @Jaytiger I found another solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386894/dynamic-unpivot-in-bigquery)

Comment: Hi @user19462600, If your issue is resolved could you add resolution steps as the answer?